# Format a string into an email Body Format

Tags: vb.net

I am using this code to send an email on my code

in this below code subject and mail body we are getting form dataset and storing in a string .

i didn't have any concern regarding subject but when it comes to body i am facing issue like

for example in my mail body i am having three points i.e, three line

```
1.some text
2.some text
3.some text
```

after the mail is triggered my mail body is looking like

```
1.some text 2.sometex 3.sometext .
```

here is my piece of code

```
Try
        Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient
        Dim mail As New MailMessage
        SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential()
        SmtpServer.Port = 25
        SmtpServer.Host = "email.host.com"
        mail = New MailMessage
        mail.From = New MailAddress("myemail@email.com")
        mail.To.Add("otheremail@email.com")
        mail.Subject = Subject
        mailbody=  "<html>" & " <body>" & "<p>" _
        & String.Join("</p><p>", mailbody.Split({Environment.NewLine}, 
        StringSplitOptions.None)) _
         & " </p>" & "</body> " & " </html>"
        mail.Body = mailbody
        mail.IsBodyHtml=true
        SmtpServer.Send(mail)

    catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

is there any way where i can get the exact format .

Please check the below screen shot
[image]

After generating the mail still i ma getting the mail is lookin like this

Comment: If you set `IsBodyHtml` to `true` then the `Body` has to actually contain HTML. I'm guessing that yours doesn't, although that's only a guess because, depsite that being the crux of your problem, you've made no attempt to show us how you actually create the body now. Edit your question and provide the FULL and CLEAR explanation that you should have to start with.

Comment: After concatenating the html tags and giving isbodythml true  i am still facing the similar issue .through smtpclient we are able to send the mail body

Comment: Why would you expect one paragraph tag to display a list on multiple lines? If you expect to be able to use HTML then you need a basic understanding of HTML. It's not really for us to teach you the basics of HTML.

Comment: What is the exact string, assigned to Body? If you save it to html, does it display correctly (in browser)? If you send your message to some client, able to see message source (Outlook likely can't display it), what is written there?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
mailbody = _
    "<html>" & " <body>" & "<p>" _
    & String.Join("</p><p>", mailbody.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)) _
    & " </p>" & "</body> " & " </html>"
```

The issue was that you were splitting the lines int he `mailbody` and we weren't closing your HTML tags properly.

Comment: i added the same piece of  code .Still i am getting the same issue .I edited the my question and attached the screen shot for your reference

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert the "Enter" in HTML (that doesn't work) replace that by `<br/>`
You can also replace the "Environment.NewLine" by `<br/>`

Use `<br/>` in HTML to bring the text to the next line.